# Strange values with Pandas DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sum

Thats my code and I get some strange values for "TradePrice" Does anyone hava clue how to solve this.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("TradesSEK.csv")
df["IBCommission"] = abs(df["IBCommission"])

sum_df = df.groupby(["Symbol", "Buy/Sell"]).sum()[["Quantity", "TradePrice", "IBCommission"]].reset_index()

#skriv ut den nya dataframe
print(sum_df)
#skriv till csv fil
sum_df.to_csv("SumTrades.csv", index=False)
```

Here is a short example for the data I try to import and Sum

```
Symbol,Buy/Sell,Quantity,TradePrice,IBCommission,CurrencyPrimary,TradeDate
FDXS MAR 22,SELL,-1,164561.432,-3.89956,SEK,2022-01-03
FDXS MAR 22,SELL,-1,164561.432,-3.89956,SEK,2022-01-03
FDXS MAR 22,SELL,-1,164561.432,-3.89956,SEK,2022-01-03
FDXS MAR 22,BUY,1,164684.576,-3.89956,SEK,2022-01-03
FDXS MAR 22,BUY,1,164674.314,-3.89956,SEK,2022-01-03
FDXS MAR 22,BUY,1,164674.314,-3.89956,SEK,2022-01-03
FDXS MAR 22,BUY,1,164684.576,-3.89956,SEK,2022-01-03
FDXS MAR 22,BUY,1,164684.576,-3.89956,SEK,2022-01-03
FDXS MAR 22,BUY,1,164684.576,-3.89956,SEK,2022-01-03
FDXS MAR 22,SELL,-1,164571.69400000002,-3.89956,SEK,2022-01-03
FDXS MAR 22,SELL,-1,164571.69400000002,-3.89956,SEK,2022-01-03
FDXS MAR 22,SELL,-1,164571.69400000002,-3.89956,SEK,2022-01-03
FDXS MAR 22,SELL,-1,164469.074,-3.89956,SEK,2022-01-03
FDXS MAR 22,SELL,-1,164469.074,-3.89956,SEK,2022-01-03
FDXS MAR 22,SELL,-1,164469.074,-3.89956,SEK,2022-01-03
FDXS MAR 22,BUY,1,164366.454,-3.89956,SEK,2022-01-03
FDXS MAR 22,BUY,1,164571.69400000002,-3.89956,SEK,2022-01-03
FDXS MAR 22,BUY,1,164571.69400000002,-3.89956,SEK,2022-01-03
FDXS MAR 22,BUY,1,164171.476,-3.89956,SEK,2022-01-03
FDXS MAR 22,BUY,1,164171.476,-3.89956,SEK,2022-01-03
FDXS MAR 22,BUY,1,164171.476,-3.89956,SEK,2022-01-03
FDXS MAR 22,SELL,-1,164458.812,-3.89956,SEK,2022-01-03
FDXS MAR 22,SELL,-1,164684.576,-3.89956,SEK,2022-01-03
FDXS MAR 22,SELL,-1,164499.86000000002,-3.89956,SEK,2022-01-03
MESH2,BUY,1,43729.370899999994,-4.729712,SEK,2022-01-04
MESH2,BUY,1,43729.370899999994,-4.729712,SEK,2022-01-04
MESH2,SELL,-1,43688.4407,-4.729712,SEK,2022-01-04
MESH2,SELL,-1,43688.4407,-4.729712,SEK,2022-01-04
MESH2,SELL,-1,43702.08409999999,-4.729712,SEK,2022-01-04
MESH2,SELL,-1,43702.08409999999,-4.729712,SEK,2022-01-04
MESH2,BUY,1,43665.7017,-4.729712,SEK,2022-01-04
MESH2,BUY,1,43711.17969999999,-4.729712,SEK,2022-01-04
MESH2,BUY,1,43297.79,-4.715152000000001,SEK,2022-01-05
MESH2,BUY,1,43297.79,-4.715152000000001,SEK,2022-01-05
MESH2,SELL,-1,43334.0604,-4.715152000000001,SEK,2022-01-05
MESH2,SELL,-1,43340.8611,-4.715152000000001,SEK,2022-01-05
```

Here is the output

```
         Symbol Buy/Sell  Quantity    TradePrice  IBCommission
0       EUR.USD     SELL -617.1651  3.196508e+01     18.271867
1   FDXS DEC 22      BUY  110.0000  1.561461e+07    455.386870
2   FDXS DEC 22     SELL -110.0000  1.529547e+07    455.386870
3   FDXS JUN 22      BUY   24.0000  3.523879e+06     94.577592
4   FDXS JUN 22     SELL  -24.0000  3.528523e+06     94.577592
5   FDXS MAR 22      BUY  172.0000  2.690855e+07    682.416426
6   FDXS MAR 22     SELL -172.0000  2.662888e+07    682.416426
7   FDXS MAR 23      BUY    3.0000  4.688854e+05     12.682500
8   FDXS MAR 23     SELL   -3.0000  4.684181e+05     12.682500
9   FDXS SEP 22      BUY   47.0000  6.480417e+06    189.812090
11  FESX MAR 22      BUY    9.0000  3.750484e+05    119.088396
12  FESX MAR 22     SELL   -9.0000  3.748532e+05    119.088396
13  FSXE MAR 22      BUY    5.0000  1.178318e+05     18.331270
14  FSXE MAR 22     SELL   -5.0000  1.175731e+05     18.331270
15        M2KH2      BUY    3.0000  5.665107e+04     15.401632
16        M2KH2     SELL   -3.0000  5.653878e+04     15.401632
17        MESH2      BUY   63.0000  2.597867e+06    301.419600
18        MESH2     SELL  -63.0000  2.512345e+06    301.419600
```

And please Dont hate totaly new to Python

I try to import data to a DataFrame and then sum all the values. It works for all columns but not "TradePrice"

Comment: What makes them strange and what would you like them to look like instead?

Comment: Hard to know without knowing the contents of df after it imports data from csv!

Comment: It should not be a value like "3.432423232+01" It should Be a big number.

Comment: `e+07` means `* 10_000_000`, it's scientific notation; so, they *are* big numbers.

Comment: You can avoid the scientific notion by setting the display option you'd like to see: i.e. `pd.set_option('display.float_format', lambda x: '%.5f' % x)`

Comment: You can also use the same method when you write to csv `df.to_csv('SumTrades.csv', float_format='%.5f')`

Comment: It is not a formatting issue as other suggest. The correct syntax is: `sum_df = df.groupby(["Symbol", "Buy/Sell"])[["Quantity", "TradePrice", "IBCommission"]].sum().reset_index()` but that is not the cause of the problem. If you take only FDXS Mar 22 then there are 12 buys and 12 sells in the sample you provide. Your code gives this correct value. It also gives the correct value for sum of TradePrice for the sample specifically 1974111.202 for Buy. So there is something going awry with your larger data as the code works. I suggest you test it on a subset such as the sample you gave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In practical terms, if the desired format is five digits after the decimal point, you can use these two commands:

- `pd.set_option('display.float_format', lambda x: '%.5f' % x)` - this will set your display format of floats to five digits.
- When you're ready to save your DataFrame to CSV, you can use  `df.to_csv('SumTrades.csv', float_format='%.5f')` to tell Pandas to use the same float format.

For further reference: [Styler](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.format.html), [options](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/options.html), [style](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/style.html)

Comment: Thanks for this! Will try this later hopefully it works as intended.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting strange numbers for TradePrice is because your statement
`sum_df = df.groupby(["Symbol", "Buy/Sell"]).sum()[["Quantity", "TradePrice", "IBCommission"]].reset_index()`
groups your dataframe rows by Symbol and Buy/Sell. It then adds ALL the numbers in the rows. You do not want the Sum of TradePrice, You would want the average so you will need another statement to generate that:

```
sum_df = df.groupby(["Symbol", "Buy/Sell"]).sum()[["Quantity", "IBCommission"]].reset_index()
sum_df['TradePrice'] = df.groupby(["Symbol", "Buy/Sell"]).mean()[["TradePrice"]]
```

That should work but I have not tested it. At any rate you should get the idea. I would also reset the output format as others have already suggested in the other answers

Comment: Actually I want the sum for "TradePrice" too. But thanks for your input.

Comment: Glad to have contributed something. So what is it that you find strange about the TradePrice totals? Is it indeed just the format that the numbers are presented in? Having worked in capital markets, I'm not sure of what value sum of TradePrice is. As a metric, i would consider it irrelevant. Why are you interested in it?

Comment: As another aside, I should point out that the average calculated by the method I described above is also inaccurate (a reasonable approximation but inaccurate nonetheless). It is calculated based on the number of trades and not the quantity. An accurate average would require a volume-weighted average, ie sum(quantity * price)/sum(quantity)